# AND on an IF condition in JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

How do you write AND on an if condition in javascript? I want to have this code but it produces an error.

```
if(xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("//RentersInsuranceSetting/Row").getAttribute("ExcludeCorporateUnits")==1) AND (xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("//AllPeople/Row").getAttribute("BusinessCorporationBit")==1)
    {  
    confirmValidRentersInsurance.required = "noReq"
    confirmValidRentersInsurance.style.color = "blue"
    insuranceRequired = false   
    }
```

what is the operator for AND in javascript?

Comment: AND operator in javascript is &&

Comment: Did you even try googling it?

Comment: i googled && and it produced an error and so i thought that its wrong. turns out that the problem was in my set of parentheses. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the `&&` operator.

You also need another set of parentheses, so that you get `if ((...) && (...))` instead of `if (...) && (...)`:

```
if ((xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("//RentersInsuranceSetting/Row").getAttribute("ExcludeCorporateUnits")==1) && (xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("//AllPeople/Row").getAttribute("BusinessCorporationBit")==1))
```

Or remove some parentheses to make it `if (... && ...)`. As the `==` operator has higher precedence than the `&&` operator, you don't need them:

```
if (xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("//RentersInsuranceSetting/Row").getAttribute("ExcludeCorporateUnits")==1 && xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("//AllPeople/Row").getAttribute("BusinessCorporationBit")==1)
```

Comment: i googled && and it produced an error and so i thought that its wrong. turns out that the problem was in my set of parentheses. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The logical "and" operator in JavaScript is `&&`.

Also here's a [quick reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

Answer (score 1):

The `&&` operator will do that. For example...

```
if (condition1 && condition2) 
{ // if 2 conditions are true, then execute this line... }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
&&
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

Maybe look at these javascript tutorials on the above web site.